# What is the base % chance to find magic items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have found a few items that say "X% better chance of finding magical items".  I want to know the base chance to find magical items to see whether this is a reasonable upgrade.

[image: Scouting Buckler]

For example, if there is a base 5% chance to find a magical item off of a normal creature, +3% is a nice boost but nothing worth writing home about.  However if the base chance is only 1%, I can easily *quadruple* my chances of getting magical loot with a simple +3% shield.

EDIT: As @Wikwocket pointed out, magic find is multiplicative. This makes the above example less relevant, but the question is still the same:

**What is the native (naked) percentage chance to find a magical item?**

(I know this varies by monster type, I would like an answer addressing them all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base/native percent chance for an item drop to be magical/set/legendary depends on monster type, difficulty level, and act. I am pretty sure drop rates for all the monster types are not yet known, except for generalities like getting better drops from elites.

Magic find is applied to these drop rates. For example, if the base chance to drop a magic item was 5%, and you have 100% magic find, there will now be a 10% chance to drop a magic item.

Comment: Ah, good point. I had assumed Magic Find was additive but multiplicative makes much more sense.

Comment: Yes, it is multiplied by the base chance. MF percentages in the hundreds were not uncommon in D2 (and were much desired).