# Is there a cap or soft-cap in % chance to find magic items?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there a cap or soft-cap in % chance to find magic items? Should I stop stacking MF items at some point?

Comment: A follow up question would be, what does a 100% (or more)MF do? It's probably not possible... Edit: I can see this has been answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66303/what-is-the-base-chance-to-find-magic-items

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Old question already answered, but since the game has seen some changes since, an update seems necessary for the newcomers:

> Currently in patch 1.0.7, the hard cap on Magic Find is 625% (300% soft
>   cap + 75% NV stacks + 250% MP 10 on Inferno).
>
> Starting in patch 1.0.8 however, the Magic Find bonus from shrines
>   will be able to exceed the “soft cap” of 300% that players can achieve
>   from a combination of their own gear and their follower’s gear. In
>   patch 1.0.8 we’re also adding a buff to multiplayer games called
>   “Strength in Numbers” which allows for a 10% bonus to Magic Find, Gold
>   Find, and experience per additional player in a multiplayer game, up
>   to a maximum of 30% in a four-player game. The Magic Find and Gold
>   find bonuses of this multiplayer feature can exceed their respective
>   300% cap as well.
>
> So after patch 1.0.8, if you have 300% Magic Find from your gear and
>   your followers, have 5 stacks of NV (+75% MF), are playing on Inferno
>   at MP10 (+250% MF), have a Fortune Shrine buff active (+25% MF), AND
>   are playing a four player multiplayer game (+30% MF), **you can hit the
>   maximum of a 680% bonus to Magic Find**. Shiny!
>
> Keep in mind that this cap will be lower for if you aren’t playing on
>   Inferno and/or aren’t using Monster Power level 10, etc.

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8568890869#8)

Answer (score 2):

Jay Wilson, Game Director of Diablo III, mentioned during a [Best Buy Developer Chat](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/diablo-iii-developer-chat-at-best-buy-2) that magic find will not be capped:

> **Guest-446:** Will certain areas in Diablo 3 have different treasure
>   classes like they did in Diablo 2 for finding higher items or does it
>   just come down to how far you have progressed into the game and is
>   there a diminishing effect of the amount of mf your character can have
>   eg. like a mf cap?
>
> **Jay Wilson:** I don’t really know how to answer the treasure class one,
>   lots of areas have different treasure classes but we try to make areas
>   relatively equal depending on challenge and monster level. MF is not
>   capped, though.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct ("treasure class" is more directly a function of MP level now, and there absolutely is a cap on MF).