# What is the minimum magic find % do make a difference on inferno dificulty?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was wondering if anyone have found a base value of magic find that works better on inferno.

I heard that 75% individually would be a good amount.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a cap or soft-cap in % chance to find magic items?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66403/is-there-a-cap-or-soft-cap-in-chance-to-find-magic-items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magic Find % multiplies the chance on the item. If an item in norm has a .0005% chance to drop, and you have 100% MF then the item now has a .0010% chance to drop. It's the same in inferno. In inferno and all difficulties, the items are just more and more rare. So you may find it harder to get items, but it's not because the individuals MF drops with difficulty, it's just items are more rare to compensate with higher level MF ratings.
To answer your question. The more the better, there's no real base amount that would be sufficient.

Comment: Actually if the rate was .0005% and you had 100% MF, the rate would then be .0010%. But your central point is correct, MF works the same in Inferno.

Comment: Oops, I'll fix that up.

Comment: It it obvious that the more the better. But if you take diablo 2 as example there where some known formulas that said that only if you have 400% mf would make some difference. Thats what I wanted to know.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you knew that it's not character dependant. Because based on your question, with the assumption that it went down with game difficulty, it must have been related to a character spec. Since it's not, literally anything is better than nothing. But even with nothing, there is always a slim slim chance that anything could drop. 

Others can comment on the topic of your 400% comment. that doesn't sound right to me. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Any amount makes a difference, but unless you're quickly killing packs of elites, you should work on your core stat, vitality, weapon damage and attack speed.

The Nephalem's Valor buff at 5 stacks gives %15 magic and gold find per stack, and persists through death.  If you're comfortable being able to quickly kill the majority of elites to get 5 stacks, then by all means add magic find.  Any small amount makes a difference.

I have 5 stacks in Inferno right now - it's %15 per stack, at least in Inferno.

Comment: It's known; 20% per stack.

Comment: it's actually 15% per stack